# How to exit fullscreen Terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, fullscreen

I have found that if you go `View > Fullscreen`:

[image: View > Fullscreen Menu]

Then it makes the Terminal fullscreen, and to exit fullscreen I have found that I have to execute the command:

```
exit
```

But that closes my entire Terminal, is there not a way to get it to exit the full screen without having to close the actual Terminal session?

Comment: By the way, you didn't even have to type `exit` and enter; just Ctrl+D would have sufficed.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, there is a very easy way. Just press <kbd>F11</kbd>.

Comment: Oh... Now I feel really silly! :D

Comment: @Toroidal: Please don't be..you are not alone..we all sometimes search for some tougher solutions while the actual one is really easy..happens to me all the time :)

Answer (score 3):

Just press <kbd>F11</kbd>. If it does not work, press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Alternative : right click on the screen, select "Leave fullscreen". Or select "Show menu bar". Uncheck Full Screen.

Answer (score 1):

- `F11` : Toogle Fullscreen
- `Ctrl + D` : exit command shortcut